# jQuery mobile grid is not showing all content

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-grid

In my jQuery mobile app some off the content is not coming on my screen. Some content is showing under my header and navbar. This is the code I used for my grid I am working with solo's and a 2 column grid.

Image of my problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/f3fs.png/

My grid code:

```
 <script id="tradeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="stock">Stock:${title}</div></div>
    </div>
   <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Type</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="position" style="width:100%">${type}</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Position</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="position" style="width:100%">${position}</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Entry</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="entry" style="width:100%">${entry}</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Stoploss</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="stoploss" style="width:100%">${stoploss}</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Target1</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="target1" style="width:100%">${target1}</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Target2</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="target1" style="width:100%">${target2}</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="shareimage" style="width:100%"><center><img  src='http://www.stock-hunter.net/system/files/styles/large/private/${screenshot.filename}' ></center>  </div></div>
        </div>
       <div class="ui-grid-solo">
           <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="explanation" style="width:100%">Explanation:  ${explanation}</div></div>
   </div>
        <div class="ui-block-solo"><div class="warning" style="width:100%">Please keep in mind  all trades are at own risk! If a level don't get touched in a straight way the trade is not valid  anymore!</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Result:${result}</div>  </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="position" style="width:100%">Post date:${creationdate} </div></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You still have `ui-block-solo`.

Answer (score 0):

This was code I found on the jquery mobile demo page.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
```

Previous
    Next
    
    
    More

Comment: What is the correct code to place into my script to show content not in grid modus but over the full space of my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also use JQM header and JQM content properly? `data-role="header"` & `data-role="content"`

Something like that, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5kfnT/7/

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <div data-role="navbar" class="test1" data-grid="d">
           <ul id="footer_nav" data-transition="none"> 
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_walloffame" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" > Wall</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_associateview" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top">Associate</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" name="menu_nav_managersview" id="menu_nav_managersview" data-icon="custom" >Managers</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_treasurechest" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Treasure</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="none" id="menu_nav_redeem" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="top" >Redeem</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block B</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block B</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block B</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:30px">Block B</div></div>
        </div><!-- /grid-a -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>footer</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello this is my JQ header and JQ content: